# Get Coldfusion to parse a json request

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a javascript object:

```
data = { color: red, day: monday, list: {1,2,3,4,5,6}}
```

I pass this to a coldfusion page using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_myPage.cfm",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json" });
```

This is my cfdump:

[image]

(the "list" is actually going to contain a list of emails but I am just testing with one address right now)

In coldfusion, I am trying to assign each "part" to a variable:

```
<cfset requestBody = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />
<!--- Double-check to make sure it's a JSON value. --->
<cfif !isJSON( requestBody )>

<!--- Echo back POST data. --->
<h3>The URL you requested does not provide valid JSON</h3>
<cfdump
var="#requestBody#"
label="HTTP Body"
/>
<cfelse>
 <cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(requestBody)>
 <cfset color = cfData.color>
 <cfset day = cfData.day>
 <cfset myList = cfData.list>
</cfif>
```

However I am getting an error with "list",

```
Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

How do I parse the list as Coldfusion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i would have sent the data as a post var,

```
data: { json: JSON.stringify(data) }
```

and then parsed it into a variable:

```
<cfset structJSON = deserializeJSON(FORM.json)>
```

At that point, `cfdump` the structure to inspect it's contents so that you know how to access them.

Since we don't know what the json structure you are passing to ColdFusion consists of, I have no idea what `structJSON.list` contains or why it would be throwing an error.

Edit: Ah i see your json now.

Your list is not valid json, change `{` and `}` to `[` and `]`.

```
data = { color: "red", day: "monday", list: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

Comment: I see...added a screenshot of my cfdump.